# Nginx + rewrite + php-fpm = confusion

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting, php

I'm moving from Apache to Nginx. I've got problem with converting Apache rewrite rules into nginx rules. What I'm trying to convert:

```
RewriteRule ^$ www/controller.php?_url_=index [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^/+$ www/controller.php?_url_=index [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9_/]*))?$ www/controller.php?_url_=$1&_req_=$2 [QSA,L]
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)controller.php?(.*)$ www/controller.php?$2 [QSA,L]
```

What I tried to use:

```
rewrite ^/$ /www/controller.php?_url_=index break;
rewrite ^/+$ /www/controller.php?_url_=index break;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*))?$ /www/controller.php?_url_=$1&_req_=$2 break;
rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)controller.php?(.*)$ /www/controller.php?$2 break;
```

If I use above rules my browser is downloading php file (server is not executing it) - I guessed it's not being passed to PHP-FPM. Somewhere I found I should replace "break;" with "last;" like:

```
rewrite ^/$ /www/controller.php?_url_=index last;
```

After replacing this still I'm downloading php file from http://example.org, but when I visit http://example.org/login I get into infinite loop. I read nginx documentation and different examples (also here at StackOverflow) but sill I can't find correct configuration. Could somebody point me into the right direction?

Here is my whole config file:

```
server {
listen       80;
server_name  10.10.100.172;
error_log    /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log debug;
rewrite_log on;


location / {
root   /var/www/webs;
    index  index.php index.html index.htm;
rewrite ^/$ /www/controller.php?_url_=index last;
    rewrite ^/+$ /www/controller.php?_url_=index last;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)(/([a-zA-Z0-9_]*))?$ /www/controller.php?_url_=$1&_req_=$2 last;
    rewrite ^/([a-zA-Z0-9/]+)controller.php?(.*)$ /www/controller.php?$2 last;
}


error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    root           /var/www/webs;
    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_index  index.php;
    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include        fastcgi_params;
}
```

}

**EDIT:**

I moved rules outside location segment and used "break;" at the end of each rule. I can reach /www/controller.php?*url*=login&*req*=/ when I go to example.org/login/ - controller.php was responsible for infinite loop. When I try to reach example.org or example.org/ I'm downloading controller.php file - like it's not being passed to the PHP-FPM. Any guess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used above rules outside location segment and it works! I tried viewing my page in different browser and ecerything is fine. I always forget about removing cache..

Comment: up for the answer :)